# Binding multiple images with MVVM in RelativeLayout dynamically?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve something like overlaying multiple transparent background images in a relative layout. So I have 1 background image and 2 foreground images that are overlaying as shown below. The code below is working perfectly fine when I define it in XAML as static, but now my requirement is to add foreground images dynamically.

So background image below is static but foreground1, foreground2, foreground3... so count of images will be determined at run time. This can be simply done in xaml.cs class by adding a child to the RelativeLayout but I am using an MVVM approach and it is hard to mix both. How can I dynamically create multiple images to overlay on a background image using MVVM?

Basically how can I create a list of images like in a ListView but instead of vertically aligning, they should overlay on each other?

```
<RelativeLayout x:Name="rlMain" Style="{StaticResource rlStyle}"   HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="background.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Height}"/>
    <Image x:Name="foreground1" Style="{StaticResource  ImageStyle}" Source="{Binding MainFrontPath, Mode=TwoWay}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Height}"/>
    <Image x:Name="foreground2" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" Source="{Binding SecFrontPath, Mode=TwoWay}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, 
             Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = 
         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
             Property=Height}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are few things in relative layout that are not supported from XAML. Its fine to add the view layout from xaml.cs, your view is still separated from VM. Or if you want a translation of cs to xaml, post your cs file too.

Comment: @Rohit I am not sure what do you mean by "in relative layout that are not supported from XAML"? Because I believe my focus is more about dynamically creating images using mvvm, not related to relative layout. Yes I am able to achieve it using xaml.cs file but I need to change entire my logic as I am binding all entire my contolpage using viewmodel. So it wont work some part bind, some part create using xaml.cs. therefore I wanted to see if any possibility doing it through Viewmodel.

Comment: You can create a control that does it for you and bind the itemsource as your image list. You can checkout example of horizontal listview.

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand your intent here so please forgive me if I'm off the mark.

You might be able to do what you want using `RelativeLayout` if you're willing to build the code to manage the application of layout constraints when each new element is added to the layout.  Having gone down that road, I would not recommend it because trying to out think `RelativeLayout`'s layout code gets complicated quickly and (more importantly) `RelativeLayout` is slow.  I say this because I've tried it and, once I' went through the processes,  I realized that building a custom layout would have been faster and much more maintainable.

So, if one were interested in doing a custom layout, here are some basics:

- You can start a custom layout as a class that inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.Layout<View>`.  As you can see from the Xamarin Forms docs, `Layout<View>` and it's parent, `Layout` are pretty simple classes.

  - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Layout%3CT%3E/
  - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Layout/
- The layout cycle is split into two portions: Measure and Placement.
- You can override the `OnMeasure` method (or `GetMeasure`, if you want to be up to date) of your custom layout to manage the Measure portion.  Here, you're telling the Xamarin Forms layout engine two things:

  - How much space you want for your layout
  - The least amount of space you need for your layout

  The interesting thing about `OnMeasure` is that you might find the built-in behavior is good enough.  I would recommend focusing on the Placement portion first and see if the space allocated by the ancestor `OnMeasure` code meets your needs.
- The `LayoutChildren` method of your custom layout is where you will do your calculations and apply your custom layout (the Placement portion of the layout cycle).  In fact, it is likely the only method you will need to override.  It is called by Xamarin Forms during the layout cycle and is provided with the location and size provided by its parent layout.
- With the location and size now available to you, you can start to calculate the position and size of your custom layout's children views/layouts within your allocated size.  Since you're doing this manually, you'll have to account for your custom layout's Padding and each child view/layout's Margin.  Once you have a child's location and size (bounds) with respect to this custom layout, you will use `LayoutChildInBoundingRegion(VisualElement child, Rectangle bounds)` to have Xamarin Forms's layout engine perform its layout.
- Looking at your design objective, one thing I don't know is what will control the order in which the images are going to overlap each other.   It is going to be either their order in the custom layout's `Children` array, the order in which you call `LayoutChild`, or both (depending on how the layout cycle is managed on different devices).  Because of this uncertainty, I would design with the assumption that it is both and call `LayoutChildren` on each child in the same order as the `Children` list.

Here is a sample custom layout with just the bare essentials:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Forms9Patch
{
    public class ManualLayout : Xamarin.Forms.Layout<View>
    {
        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            // layout calculations go here.  Don't forget to account for 
            // this layout's Padding and each child view's/layout's Margin.
            // for the sake of this example, let's say I've stored these 
            // calculation results in:
            Dictionary<View, Rectangle> bounds = new Dictionary<View, Rectangle>();

            // And with those calculation results, I can apply the layouts.
            foreach (var child in Children)
                LayoutChild(child, bounds[child]);
        }
    }
}
```

With complete control over your custom layout, you will be amazed at what kind of custom layouts you can build.  Now that I've had some experience with it, quite frankly I like it very much and, because of it's speed, have started to rely on it quite a bit.

Again, sorry if this advice is misdirected.

Comment: I have actually achieved something similar with custom layout but I was inheriting from RelativeLayout and creating a bindable itemsource, instead of Layout. I wasn't aware about your approach. Thanks for sharing. it looks really interesting. I am going to try this asap and let you know about the results.